# Integrations between web apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, api, integration

I have an existing Ruby on Rails app which has own email+password authentication. My customers have a wide variety of invoicing apps and they are asking me to add integrations between my app and their invoicing apps.

Let's assume that there are 10 different invoicing apps which needs to integrate to my app. All those apps have REST APIs. What are the concrete steps to proceed?

My main goal is to get some of customer's data from invoicing app to my app.

Answer (score 0):

Create code in your app that connects to the REST services on the other apps and get the data from the applications to your own application.